Change SOAP_RPC_LITERAL to SOAP_DOCUMENT_LITERAL
I am making quite simple request - but it is rejected from the server.
Server demands SOAP_DOC_LITERAL, and my request is recognized on the
server as SOAP_RPC_LITERAL. I've copied xml envelope from SOAP UI, where
same call passes through as SOAP_DOC_LITERAL and it's all good.
What is the difference between SOAP UI call and call from my application?
How can I change request to SOAP_DOC_LITERAL?
Code:
internal class Program
{        
    public static void Execute()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"
                    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                    xmlns:cus=""http://siebel.com/CustomUI"" 
                    xmlns:mtel=""http://www.siebel.com/xml/Mtel%20Order%20Integration"">
                        <soapenv:Header>
                            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext"">
                                <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility"">
                                    <wsse:Username>TEST</wsse:Username>
                                    <wsse:Password Type=""wsse:PasswordText"">TEST</wsse:Password>
                                </wsse:UsernameToken>
                            </wsse:Security>
                        </soapenv:Header>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <cus:UpsertProvisioningStatusData_Input>
                                <Order>
                                    <orderId>1-3XWV7UR</orderId>                                
                                    <LineItem>
                                        <itemId>1-3XWV80L</itemId>
                                        <activationDate>11/12/2024 01:00:00</activationDate>
                                        <deactivationDate/>
                                        <actionDate>11/12/2024 01:00:00</actionDate>
                                        <status>OK</status>
                                        <comments/>
                                    </LineItem>
                                </Order>
                            </cus:UpsertProvisioningStatusData_Input>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>");

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://mywebsite.com");
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Execute();
    }
}

